# Disable Add Block on Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am trying to parse information on safeway items for sale at a particular location at the URL http://weeklyspecials.safeway.com/customer_Frame.jsp?drpStoreID=970.

However I cannot parse past the HTML id storeLocator as a print statement in my emulator says "Sorry, we are unable to display our weekly adds as Add Blocking seems to be enabled on your computer...(part of a much longer message)"

How can I disable the Add Blocker so I can parse past it in my emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ad blocker in your emulator.

You are attempting to scrape a Web site that does not support scraping. In fact, while IANAL, their site terms of service suggest that what you are trying to do is in violation of those terms.

I suggest that you work with a grocery store that has a Web service API and supports the creation of third-party apps using their data.